# How to unit test protorpc calls on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unit-testing

I can use ProtoRPC from within App Engine by following the directions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/.  However, I want to write a unit test, and when I try to import protorpc, it fails:

```
ImportError: No module named protorpc
```

What do I need to do to import it outside of an App Engine context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a PYTHONPATH issue.

First, find the directory where you installed the App Engine library.  For me, I just put it in my home directory: `/home/$USER/google_appengine`.  We're looking for the lib/protorpc-1.0 directory inside of it.  For me, this directory is `/home/$USER/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0`

Now, append this to your PYTHONPATH:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/$USER/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0
```

If you update this for the correct directory, then these directions should work until the protorpc directory changes.

You probably want to add this to your .bashrc, .zshrc, or whatever the correct shell config file is for you so that the setting persists.